# After using Custom Authorization in Power BI report server, I cannot add the group in the Row level security section

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, custom-authentication, reportserver

After use [Custom Authorization](https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services) in power bi report server in Row level security part cannot assign group of database And also I checked the codes of Authorization.cs, AuthenticationUtilities.cs and AuthenticationExtension.cs classes, I didn't find a method related to Row level security that I can develop.

I was able to develop the security part that checks the permission of each report based on the group and users of my database, but I ran into trouble in the Row level security part and I did not find a method to develop.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no way to handle groups in RLS in custom auth.

https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/issues/188

and

> If you're using custom authentication in Power BI Report Server, [USERNAME()] returns the username format you’ve set up for users.

[Row-level security (RLS) in Power BI Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/row-level-security-report-server)

So in your model you set up RLS rules based on the username format you passed from your custom auth extension.